# Архивация jar файла

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Вот написал сайт, для создания фейка jimm best! (Вы наверное уже поняли о чём я). Ну и естественно файл архива *.jar, а на php архиватор zip (на сколько я знаю), после упаковки в архив нужного* .class файла при запуске приложения выходит "Ошибка приложения". Кто нибудь может подсказать каким способом ещё можно его заархивировать? (( вот код:

```
<?
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('name.jar') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('dir/name.class', 'newname.class');
    $zip->close();
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

(имена файлов тута поддельные, на сервере всё стоит верно!)

Comment: Разве ZipArchive не предназначен для zip-архивации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй переименовать *.jar в* .zip (а потом обратно, если надо), если не сработает попробуй "чистый" зип заархивированный старым алгоритмом (версией зипа)

Answer (score 0):

Вскрой исходники и сделай все через eclipse. Как создавать проект и тд говорить не буду, все просто.

Как все будет готово выполни:

```
File => Export => Jar file...
```